# Retrieve Google Cloud Pricing Information with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently trying to retrieve Google cloud pricing information via Nodejs. The goal is to figure out what the current price of a compute engine instance is for a specific machine type.

Probably I have to use the billing catalog api but I am unable to make it work at all.

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/billing/latest/google.cloud.billing.v1.CloudCatalog.html

I managed to retrieve the service id via the catalog api but that appears to be pretty pointless so far.

```
 >    const { CloudCatalogClient } = require('@google-cloud/billing')
 >    const client = new CloudCatalogClient()
 >    const list = await client.listServices()
 >         
 >    list.map(s => {
 >     s.map(a => {
 >      if(a.displayName === 'Compute Engine'){
 >       console.log(a)
 >      }
 >     })
 >          
 >    })
```

Outcome:

```
> {     
>  name: 'services/6F81-5844-456A',     
>  serviceId: '6F81-5844-456A',    
>  displayName: 'Compute Engine',    
>  businessEntityName: 'businessEntities/GCP'  
> }
```

Could somebody help me out a bit? Thank you very much.

Comment: I also have exactly the same requirement,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this

https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api

Steps

1. Get services:

   GET https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services?key=API_KEY
2. Getting the list of SKUs for a service :

   GET https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/SERVICE_ID/skus?key=API_KEY

See below test cases for the SDK you can probably use exiting SDK

[Catalog API test cases](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-billing/blob/master/test/gapic_cloud_catalog_v1.ts)

Comment: Yes and no. I know this page but I couldn't figure out how it works with proper js code. Although after days of looking I just found this page: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list
It has an js example at the very end. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I also have exactly the same requirement but in java. I have to find the current price of a compute engine instance is for a specific machine type in java. Could you please help here. I cannot see any example at page end  https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list